# Javascript printing things that are not inside the code

Tags: javascript

I have this code in my JS

```
var customer = {
    name: "John Jack",
    speak: function(){
        return "my name is "+name;
    },
    address:{
        street: '123 main st',
        city: 'Pittsburgh',
        state: 'PA'
    }
}

document.write(customer.speak());
```

In my HTML i expected

```
my name is John Jack
```

But instead i got something really weird

```
my name is Peaks mirroring in a lake below, Stubai Alps, Austria
```

I have some theories that this is somehow connected to the Chrome extension i'm using called "Pixlr",but i don't see how my js code could connect to that.I tried changing variable name and `speak` to `say`,but it still prints the same thing.What's wrong?

Comment: did you try renaming customer ?

Comment: You probably want `"my name is "+ this.name;`

Comment: @FastSnail i just did and it didn't work neither

Comment: @Mark_M oh right,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `name` with `this.name`

```js
var customer = {
  name: "John Jack",
  speak: function() {
    return "my name is " + this.name;
  },
  address: {
    street: '123 main st',
    city: 'Pittsburgh',
    state: 'PA'
  }
}

document.write(customer.speak());
```